# Drupal: Update page title based on selection in exposed filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am trying to develop a basic job portal using Drupal 7. As you can see in the image below, I have an exposed filter as a block in the left sidebar, where visitors can filter by industries and job type.

What I'd like to do is modify that "Job & Internship Opportunities" title at the top based on the user's industry selection. So, for example, if the user chose consulting, the title would become "Job & Internship Opportunities: Consulting".

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

[image: Screenshot of my job portal]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the title as people select different options on the fly then you'll need to use javascript (jQuery will be easiest).

Something like:

```
$('#industry-field').change(function(){
    $('.title').html('Job & Internship Opportunities '+$(this).val());
});
```

Or if you want to only update the title when the form is submitted then you can use [drupal_set_title](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7), possibly in [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7).